# Are destructors overloadable?

Tags: c++, syntax, destructor, overloading

[enable_if doc page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html) says:

> Constructors and destructors do not
>   have a return type; an extra argument
>   is the only option.

Are destructors overloadable?

Comment: +1 good observation. Though the answer is "no".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[**No**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#cant-overload-dtors)

---

Answer (score 8):

> Are destructors overloadable?

The answer is plain **No**.
Two versions of desturctor cannot co-exist in a `class` body.

However unlike the popular belief, note that destructor does have 2 syntax.

```
struct E {
  ~E();  // syntax-1
  ~E() throw(); // syntax-2
};
```

Syntax-2 is less popular. But it is mandatory, if the base class destructor contains similar syntax. The best example is [inheriting `std::exception`](http://ideone.com/qhETpX).

Note that, not complying to such syntax results in:

> error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual E::~E()’

Answer (score 1):

**NO** 
**Why?** 
Because destructor doesn't take any parameters and to overload any function you have two conditions:

1. Functions must have different numbers of arguments
2. Functions must have different types of arguments

But as destructors don't have any arguments we cant overload them.